# travis: sh: 0: Can't open /etc/init.d/xvfb

Tags: continuous-integration, ubuntu-16.04, travis-ci

My travis CI uses Ubuntu 14.04 and Node.js 8. My `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 8
sudo: required
addons:
    chrome: stable
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
install:
  - npm set progress=false
  - npm install
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run test
  - npm run e2e
  - npm run build
```

I've tried to update it to use Ubuntu 16.04 and Node.js 10 by changing it to:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '10'
dist: xenial
sudo: required
addons:
    chrome: stable
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
install:
  - npm set progress=false
  - npm install
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run test
  - npm run e2e
  - npm run build
```

However now I'm getting error when trying to start `xvfb`:

> 0.00s$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
>
> sh: 0: Can't open /etc/init.d/xvfb
>
> The command "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start" failed and exited with 127 during .

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution was to remove `sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start` from the `before_script` array and simply introduce `xvfb` in the `services` array.

So my `.travis.yml` now looks like this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '10'
dist: xenial
sudo: required
services:
  - xvfb
addons:
    chrome: stable
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
install:
  - npm set progress=false
  - npm install
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run test
  - npm run e2e
  - npm run build
```

Comment: Yes, just forgot to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In addition to accepted answer I would say the result config should be a bit clearer in accordance to travis docs [Using xvfb to Run Tests That Require a GUI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-xvfb-to-run-tests-that-require-a-gui). You don't need to set `DISPLAY`, so `before_script` section becomes excessive:

> This only works on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and later on releases i.e. with dist: xenial or dist: bionic 
>   The following will start xvfb and set the right values for the DISPLAY environment variable...

Also you don't need to specify dist in 2019 for node_js, because `xenial` is the default image for `node_js` language now ([blogpost](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-04-15-xenial-default-build-environment)). Previously it was `trusty`, so another possible solution might be in specifying dist as `trusty` (see the [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-xvfb-directly)). But speaking of default, the discussed config might look like

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '10'
sudo: required
services:
  - xvfb
addons:
    chrome: stable
install:
  - npm set progress=false
  - npm install
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run test
  - npm run e2e
  - npm run build
```